# msyterious value change - call by reference?

Tags: php

I'm working on a project, that basically maps some data from one table to a second one.
I'm iterating over lists of products, finding out for which languages i have translations.

i have the following code:

```
foreach ($allLanguages AS $languageID => $language) {
        foreach ($allProducts AS $singleProduct) {
            if (in_array ($languageID, $productLanguages[$singleProduct->id])) {
                $singleProduct->lang_id = $productId;
                $singleProduct->language = $language['language'];
                $singleProduct->country = $language['country'];
                print $singleProduct->id . " - " .$language['language']."_".$language['country']."\n";
                $languageProducts[] = $singleProduct;

                $productId ++;
            }
        }
    }

    print "after loops: \n";
    foreach ($languageProducts AS $product) {
        print $product->id . " - " .$product->language."_".$product->country."\n";
    }
```

it produces output like this:

```
// put any code in {}
1 - de_DE  
2 - de_DE  
3 - de_DE  
1 - de_AT  
2 - de_AT
```

after loops:

```
1 - de_AT  
2 - de_AT  
3 - de_DE  
1 - de_AT  
2 - de_AT
```

the first five lines (the output from inside) is correct (as per the data i have) and expected. 
But then, the values "mysteriously" change from the correct ones inside the loop to the wrong ones outside.
it looks like they were overwritten, but the overall number of lines is still correct. The one record that only exists in de_DE is unchanged.

So i'm left to guessing: is this some kind of call-by-reference - Problem?
Could someone point me in the right direction? 
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `echo "Working on object : "; var_dump($singleProduct);` just inside your inner `foreach` loop, you will see that you're working on the same object instance IDs for each language.

You will need to clone the object to get a copy of it.

```
foreach($allProducts as $singleProduct) {
    $singleProduct = clone $singleProduct;
    // ...
}
```

This will give you copies of the objects that don't overwrite each other.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. Although i'm not sure i fully understand what's happening here